# Limiting the Archive page to posts posted by particular author

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, archive-template, permalinks

I am on Archive Page of a custom post type `gallery`.

I have introduced custom permalink variable - `author_id`.

Lets say i get the permalink variable in `$perm_author_id`. I want to compare `$perm_author_id` and `get_the_author_meta(ID)` and then display the posts if they are equal.

How can I limit posts displayed on the archive page on to those posts posted by author whose `author_id` is present in permalink?

Comment: You've added author ID to which permalinks? Authors already have their own archives, `/author/author-name/`.

Comment: i have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

```
function comment_author_id($query) {
    $author_id = get_query_var( 'hotel_name' );
    if ($author_id) {
      $query->set('author', $author_id);
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'comment_author_id' );
```

Comment: Dont i have to use some hook?

Comment: please tell me if `pre_get_posts` can be used or if i have to use something else

Comment: I think you have a choice between using a hook (function.php) or make a WP_Query xxxx.php in the archive-file.

WP_Query seems easier to do with the previous code.

Comment: thanks this code works fine....but i want it to be limited it to only gallery post type

Comment: you can use **$query->set('post_type','gallery')** if you prefer hook or put post_type as argument with WP_Query

Comment: yes but using both of these will limit all the queries to both of these and other queries will not execute

Comment: The most correct solution is to use a WP_Query in archive-xxx.php file or custom template . You can generate the WP_Query with http://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Comment: you should *not* create a new WP_Query, but rather check the contents of `$query` and use `is_main_query` to target specific queries.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is commonly known as modifying the main query. There are a lot of faulty advice out there on topic, guiding to make the modification in template — **don't**.

The most common approach has following steps:

1. Use appropriate hook, typically this would be `pre_get_posts`.
2. Check that you work with correct instance of query object, using its methods. In your case to verify that it's *main* query and required archive.
3. Modify query by adding your custom author argument.

It's a little vague how you have implemented the permalink logic, but some searching and reading up on `pre_get_posts` should get you started.

Comment: i have updated my post